# BizTalk send port with NTLM authentication and custom user and password

Tags: .net, web-services, integration, biztalk, ntlm

I want to set up a send port in BizTalk that can send requests to a service that uses

NTLM authentication.

I have tried using WCF-BasicHTTp with TransportCredentialOnly and NTLM but I believe that

BizTalk uses the account used by the host.

Is it possible to specify a custom username and password?

Comment: Did you try to use `WCF-Custom` as transport, which lets you assign custom credentials?

Comment: If possible, you could also try to use the SOAP transport, where the credential options can be set as required

Comment: Can you clarify a bit?  NTLM and 'custom username and password' would be mutually exclusive.  Which are you trying to use?

Comment: I successfully consumed the service in SoapUI using NTLM authentication where I specified the username and password. That is the reason I wanted to try that using BizTalk. It is possible that I can use some other authentication type as well, but I dont know for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is using NTLM authentication then trying to set the user name and password has no effect as it will use the identity of the host user.  So no, you can't specify a custom username and password.

So if you want to use another user you would have to create a host running under that user, however that opens up a can of worms as that user would have to be a member of the Windows Group that the other host users run under.

**Edit**
The other suggestion that others have made is to use a custom binding, this is blog
[Yet on BizTalk Impersonation With WCF Adapters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabriccat/archive/2010/06/23/yet-on-biztalk-impersonation-with-wcf-adapters.aspx) by Paolo Salvatori goes into detail how to achieve that.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, and I was being a jerk by trying to threadjack this to talk about what NTLM implies (and what it doesn't).  That really isn't helpful in answering the question, and my complaint is with the BizTalk transports in the first place.  Apologies.